# How to make TinyMCE have a real WYSIWYG behavior - TinyMCE 4.x

Tags: jquery, html, css, tinymce

I'm working on a custom CMS and I'm using tinymce to allow my user to create the content of a page. Something similar as what you have on Wordpress. The content saved on the admin area will be displayed inside a certain element under different 
css rules.

My problem is the following, when I'm adding html elements such as headers, paragraphs, uls, ols, and many others I get a generic kind of styled html (generic css?) inside the 'textarea' is there a way that I can display all the elements in the editor using the exact same css that I will be using to display the content ?

Comment: I think if you try to inspect the code you will find the css applied to the elements.

Comment: That doesn't help me, I want to add css not edit the css that the library uses. I found a way, I'll answer my own question

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to do it.

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:content_css

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    content_css : "/mycontent.css"    // resolved to http://domain.mine/mycontent.css
});
```